# Change columns from pixel width to percentage width to be responsive and fill the table in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Currently, each column has a pixel width. So there are 2 issues I'd like ot tackle here: 1.) If there are only a few columns, I’d like columns to fill the entire table so there is not empty space. So for example, if there are 3 columns, each of those columns will be 33.33% wide. 2.) We'd like to remove avoid horizontal scrolling by either having the column widths fit to the content or also allowing cell content to wrap if we need to. Bonus: If there's a way to say, "Hey if there are an extremely high number of columns (like 70 columns for example), then use a horizontal scroll" that'd be awesome! Thanks for any help!!

Instead of this:
[pixelWidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtA0x.png)
Like this:
[percentageWidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VXPr.png)

and

Instead of this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnlPb.png)
Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8uvt.png)

Comment: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: [columnApi.autoSizeColumns(), api.sizeColumnsToFit()](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#resizing-example)